# DBC.TABLESV requesttext column gets update with "CREATE INDEX ..." command instead of maintaining the original Table definition SQL

Tags: sql, database, teradata

DBC.TABLESV requesttext column gets update with:

> "CREATE INDEX ..."

Command instead of maintaining the original Table definition SQL in Teradata. After creating a table the dbc.tablesv requesttext column returns the original definition SQL for that particular table, but after creating an index on that table, the requesttext column gets updated with the SQL for creating that particular index.

So, my question is, how can I still maintain the original definition SQL for that particular table even after an index is created against that table?

Comment: An index is part of the table definition, so I don't understand what you are asking

Comment: You can use `SHOW TABLE` to "reverse engineer" a table definition (which then would include your new index) from the table header and other attributes that are in DBC tables. Or you can save  the original `CREATE TABLE` DDL externally.